# When does an algebraic space that is a torsor over a scheme have to be a scheme?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, principal-bundles, algebraic-spaces

In *Group actions on stacks and applications* (Section 4 of part A), M.Romagny gives a definition of $G$-torsor over a scheme $S$ in which the total space need not be a scheme, just an algebraic space. He says "in general such a torsor will not be a scheme, unless (for example) $G$ is quasi-affine".

**Q.1:** Do you have a reference for the assertion that an algebraic space torsor is a scheme if the structure group is quasi-affine?

**Q.2:** For $G$ non quasi-affine (e.g. an elliptic curve) what could be an example in which the total space fails to be a scheme?

**Q.3:** More generally, are there criteria for which such torsor is a scheme?

Comment: Check out http://arxiv.org/abs/1501.04304 .

Comment: For Q1, I think you consider the sheaf of rings of functions on the torsor, which etale-locally has a lot of sections, and hence Zariski-locally has a lot of sections, because of descent for quasi coherent sheaves. Then the relative spec contains as an open subset your quasi-affine torsor.

Comment: The paper cited by Ariyan (which I have not read) is presented as a simplified version of the example in Raynaud's thesis (LNM 119, XIII.3.2). See also loc. cit. VI.2.5 for Q3: if $S$ is normal and noetherian and $G$ is smooth with connected fibers on $S$, then every $G$-torsor is locally quasiprojective over $S$.

Comment: For Q1, a precise reference is SGA1, Exp. VIII, Cor. 7.9. In fact SGA1, Exp. VIII, sec. 7 gives a list of criteria as in your Q3.